Kafka Cluster connecting from outside docker host machine not working
I have a question that I cannot get past. I cannot connect from an External machine to the Kafka Cluster. I can only locally from the Docker host.
#SUCCESS On the docker host (192.168.2.14) where the docker-compose file below is run.
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server 192.168.2.14:9092
       message_shown_topic

#FAIL On another machine (192.168.2.13) I can see it connects because it wouldn't be able to see that 9094 is also there.
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server 192.168.2.14:9092,192.168.2.14:9093  
      [2024-05-15 14:59:11,657] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node 1 (/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
      [2024-05-15 14:59:11,662] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node 2 (/127.0.0.1:9093) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
      [2024-05-15 14:59:11,662] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node 3 (/127.0.0.1:9094) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

Of course, all comes up perfectly when the docker-compose.yaml file below is run as I can list the topics
(https://medium.com/@erkndmrl/kafka-cluster-with-docker-compose-5864d50f677e)
kafka-1:
  image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
  ...
  environment:
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka-1:19092,EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9092,DOCKER://host.docker.internal:29092
    KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:19092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092,DOCKER://0.0.0.0:29092
    KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,DOCKER:PLAINTEXT
  ...

kafka-2:
  image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
  ...
  environment:
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka-2:19093,EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9093,DOCKER://host.docker.internal:29093
    KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:19093,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9093,DOCKER://0.0.0.0:29093
    KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,DOCKER:PLAINTEXT
  ...

kafka-3:
  image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
  ...
  environment:
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka-3:19094,EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9094,DOCKER://host.docker.internal:29094
    KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:19094,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9094,DOCKER://0.0.0.0:29094
    KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,DOCKER:PLAINTEXT

@Onecricketeer, while this works for the second server (192.168.2.13) a third server that has a Kubernetes Kafka client pod can see the version but all other commands fail. The only difference that I can see is the different network
#FAIL 
I have no name!@mmi-medic-kafka-client-360:/$ /opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server 192.168.2.14:9092
    Error while executing topic command : Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listTopics 

#SUCCESS 
I have no name!@mmi-medic-kafka-client-360:/$ /opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --version --bootstrap-server 192.168.2.14:9092    
3.6.2


What happens when you replace ${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}  with 192.168.2.14 so that that IP is actually advertised? Or otherwise set the environment variable DOCKER_HOST_IP=192.168.2.14 before running compose up? Notice that the error returns 127.0.0.1, not the bootstrap address you have given

In the end a full reboot of the machines I was using made this work. I did hardcode the IP Address though as OneCricketeer suggested. I couldn't see the forest for the trees.

The --version argument returns the local cli version, I believe znot communicates with an external broker. There's a separate --timeout argument and there are better ways to test network access such as netcat / telnet / kcat
